# AssociationTypeMismatch (User(#301360) expected, got Hash(#88300)) in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I try to create an Object from nested json. But I get a AssociationTypeMismatch error.
I am new to ruby on rails and not sure, it is the right way to do this.
I am thankful for any tips.


The error appears in this line "@avatar.from_json(json)" in the avatars_controller.rb

Avatar.rb

```
class Avatar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
end
```

User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :avatar
end
```

json

```
[
 {
    "id": 7,
    "user": {
        "id": 47,
        "gender": "male",
        "name": "Mark",
        "created_at": "2015-01-07T11:44:50.991Z",
        "updated_at": "2015-01-28T14:39:03.900Z"
    },
    "login_counter": 5,
    "created_at": "2015-01-28T14:39:03.896Z",
    "updated_at": "2015-03-03T12:11:43.432Z"
}
]
```

avatars_controller.rb

```
def get_data_button  
  json= open("http..." ).read
  @avatar = Avatar.new
  @avatar.from_json(json)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @avatar.save
      format.html { redirect_to user_url  }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
    end
  end
end

def avatar_params
  params.require(:avatar).permit( :login_counter, user: [:gender, :name])
end
```

Comment: change this line `params.require(:avatar).permit( :login_counter, user_attributes: [:gender, :name])`...

Comment: @DaveNewton The exception appears in this line "@avatar.from_json(json)"

Comment: @freshgrand Have you tried what I asked.. ?

Comment: Is `json` a `Hash` ?

Comment: To be honest, i dont really know. I got the json representation above and now I try to create and object from that.

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this code.

```
params.require(:avatar).permit( :login_counter, user_attributes: [:gender, :name])

[
 {
"id": 7,
"user_attributes": {
    "id": 47,
    "gender": "male",
    "name": "Mark",
    "created_at": "2015-01-07T11:44:50.991Z",
    "updated_at": "2015-01-28T14:39:03.900Z"
},
"login_counter": 5,
"created_at": "2015-01-28T14:39:03.896Z",
"updated_at": "2015-03-03T12:11:43.432Z"
```

}
]

Comment: Yes, I saw your comments late

Comment: Can you please let me know your form for this bcoz your params is not looking good, params should have user_attributes .

Comment: @freshgrand, please try above json

Comment: @ROR,  json comes from a test api, but i can't change it.